# Event ID 10009 on Server 2008 R2 DCOM was unable to communicate with computer X

Tags: windows-server-2008, dcom

On Windows Server 2008 R2 I am getting a DCOM event error 10009 "DCOM was unable to communicate with computer X" I can't ping computer X, I don't know what computer X is, and computer X is not in AD. What can I do to either fix this or make it so the events are not logged.

Comment: I can't find any useful information from Google. I would give a bounty for this but don't have enough rep points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that computer X is trying to communicate with your server, but the communication fails and the event gets logged on the server too; having the event there doesn't necessarily mean the server itself initiated the connection.

About what it could be... well, practically *anything*. DCOM is the underlying protocol for almost anything that Windows does on the network and is not plain file sharing.

If you can't resolve the host name of computer X to an IP address and don't have any other way to fint it, then your only option is using a network sniffer on the server to see where the traffic is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

WMI uses DCOM underneath, so if you have any scripts or monitoring that uses WMI, those scripts could be misconfigured and trying to contact the unknown server.

Comment: This turned out to be my situation. A network monitoring tool, Level Platforms Onsite Manager, was attempting to check WMI almost continuously on any device that had a pulse, regardless of whether or not it was a Windows box.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is still partially unknown. The best I could figure out was that there is a printer or thin client on the network that isn't on the domain.